# Show that $(AB)^T = A^T B^T$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are square commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need some help in proving the equation $(AB)^T = A^T * B^T$

Down below is me trying to solve this.. please tell me if i made any errors

$(AB)^T = B^T  A^T = (B^T  A^T)^T = (A^T)^T  (B^T)^T = AB = \cdots $

this is as far as I got, i will appreciate any help given

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
AB= ((AB)^T)^T=(A^T B^T)^T=(B^T)^T (A^T)^T =BA
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

One direction is obvious. The other direction, we need to show that if $(AB)^T = A^TB^T$, then A and B are square commuting matrices.

AB is defined, so $nCol(A) = nRow(B)$. $A^TB^T$ is defined, so $nCol(A^T) = nRow(A) = nRow(B^T) = nCol(B)$ Now, $(AB)^T$ has dimensions $nCol(B) * nRow(A)$. $A^TB^T$ has dimensions $nCol(A) * nRow(B)$. Thus we have $nCol(B) = nCol(A)$ and $nRow(A) = nRow(B)$. Combining all equalities, we have that they are square matrices.

$(AB)^T = A^TB^T = B^TA^T$. Apply transpose to last equality. You get $(A^TB^T)^T = (B^TA^T)^T \implies BA = AB$.